# How to use local image with prop from json file in thumbnail?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I tried to use local image in thumbnail(native base v2) with prop from my json file for list

In my code ,  I got Syntax Error at item.image
this file is in screens folder

[image syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avwdc.png)

```
{this.state.dataFiltered.map((item, index)=>(
        <ListItem avatar key={item.id}>
          <Left>
            <Thumbnail source={require({item.image})} />
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Text style={{color:'#fff'}} >{item.name}</Text>
            <Text note>{item.details}</Text>
          </Body>
        </ListItem>
      ))}
```

my json

```
[
  {
    "setId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Acc",
    "details": "details1",
    "image": "../src/medi_data/image/jeng.jpg"
  },
  {
    "setId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Bcc",
    "details": "details2",
    "image": "../src/medi_data/image/jeng.jpg",
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the value like this:

```
const imageUrl = require('./assets/snack-icon.png') ;
<Thumbnail source={imageUrl} />
```